# Objective-C - Replace all double new lines with 1 new line?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I have an html string, and I want to allow 1 linebreak at a time. I am trying to replacing all "\n\n" with "\n". But at the end I end up with double line-breaks.

Is it possible to print the content of a string to see what the content is, so instead of going to a new line display "\n" in the output window.

```
while ((range = [html rangeOfString:@"\n\n"]).length) 
{
   [html replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@"\n"];
}
```

**EDIT:** html has been converted to plain text (so there are no BR tags in the string)

Comment: You tagged this [nsstring] but `html` is a `NSMutableString` right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an indeterminate number of newlines that you want to compress into one, you can use NSRegularExpression. Something like:

```
NSRegularExpression *squeezeNewlines = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\n+" options:0 error:nil];
[squeezeNewlines replaceMatchesInString:html options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [html length]) withTemplate:@"\n"];
```

(Written in my browser and not tested since I don't have a recent Mac on hand, so let me know if I messed anything up.)

Comment: @aryaxt: Yep. It was added to iOS in 4.0 and to Mac OS X in Lion.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use instead:

```
- (NSUInteger)replaceOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement options:(NSStringCompareOptions)opts range:(NSRange)searchRange
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have "\n\n\n" sequences in your html file?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why replaceOccurrencesOfString wouldn't work for me. But the logic I have should work, because it loops until there are no more "double new lines"